# Batch file to remove data from a file

Tags: string, batch-file, file-manipulation

I am trying to remove any data from a file after the entry [TEST]

E.g.

The text file is:

> Random Text 1
>
> Random Text 2
>
> Random Text 3
>
> [TEST] Random Text 4
>
> Random Text 5
>
> Random Text 6 ....

After I run the batch file I just want it to remove any data after the string [TEST] so the new file will look like:

> Random Text 1
>
> Random Text 2
>
> Random Text 3

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: [replace text in file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60034/how-can-you-find-and-replace-text-in-a-file-using-the-windows-command-line-envir)  . Just replace `[TEST]` with empty string.

Comment: Wouldn't that just remove [TEST] ? Wouldn't I still be left with a file with data after that point?

Comment: aah. Misunredstood the question.

Comment: Use a `for /F` loop to read the text file; in the loop body, check the line for occurrence of `[TEST]`; if not found, echo the line; if found, put `goto :Label`; place the target `:Label` after the loop...

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off

set file_to_process=#

for /f "skip=2 tokens=1 delims=[]" %%# in  ('find /i /n "[test]" "%file_to_process%"') do (
    set line=%%#
    goto :break_for
)
:break_for
echo %line%

break>"%temp%\empty"&&fc "%temp%\empty" "%file_to_process%" /lb  %line% /t |more +4 | findstr /B /E /V "*****" > temp

rem move temp "%file_to_process%"
```

set the path to the file you want to process at the second line.If content in the `temp` file is ok you can uncomment the last line.